# Creating a nested for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, joptionpane, nested-loops

So while trying to create a random number generator that would prompt a user to keep guessing the number generated until they got it right, I ran into some problems.

Everything was working fine until I tried to add the option to play again. The problem is that if they guess the wrong number, it keeps endlessly repeating the the same error message, whether they guessed too high, too low, or if it was an invalid input, continuously. If the number is guessed right on the first time, everything works fine and it prompts to play again and works perfectly.

The thing is, I used 2 for loops because when they start guessing, I don't want:

"This program will generate a random number from 0 to 100 which you have to guess."

To be outputted every single time when they guess the wrong answer, I only want it to be outputted when they chose the option to play again, which is the reason why I made a nested for loop. But the problem still stands that the inner for loop goes in an endless cycle after the first wrong guess displaying the same answer.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;

public class RandomNumberGuesser{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        UIManager m1=new UIManager();
        Color g = Color.gray;
        Color lg = g.brighter();
        m1.put("OptionPane.background", lg);
        m1.put("Panel.background", lg);

        int x;
        for(x = 1; true; x++){
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "This program will generate a random number from 0 to 100 which you have to guess.",
            "Number Guesser",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Guess a number.",
                "Guess",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if(guess == null){
                    System.out.println("The user has terminated the program");
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
            int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);

            int y;
            for(y = 1; true; y++){
                if(guess1 > 100 || guess1 < 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Guess is out of range!\nPlease enter valid input.",
                    "Invalid Input",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            else if(randomNumber > guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed too low.\nGuess again!",
                    "Your guess",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else if(randomNumber < guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed too high.\nGuess again!",
                    "Your guess",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You guessed the number right!\nIt took you "+y+" attempt(s) to guess it.",
                    "Congratulations!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Want to play again?", "Play again?",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("Play again soon!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else{
                    y = 0;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(x = 1; true; x++){` makes me cry, use a `while` for that kind of thing. If you want to exit, just set some variable to a value so the outer loop knows that it has to `break`, too (there are better ways but I think it is better to start slowly).

Comment: "Break" only gets you out of the innermost loop. You want to create some flags to do what you want to do (instead of a simple "true" ).

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm a beginner. I'm just starting to learn programming in general. So could you give an example of how it should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class RandomNumberGuesser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // UIManager m1=new UIManager();
    Color g = Color.gray;
    Color lg = g.brighter();
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", lg);
    UIManager.put("Panel.background", lg);

    Random random = new Random();
    int attempts = 0; // Number of attempts

    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(randomNumber);

    // This outside the loop so is showed just ONE time
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "This program will generate a random number from 0 to 100 which you have to guess.", "Number Guesser", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    while (true) {

        attempts++;

        String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Guess a number.",
                "Guess", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (guess == null) {
            System.out.println("The user has terminated the program");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);

            if (guess1 > 100 || guess1 < 0)
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(
                                null,
                                "Guess is out of range!\nPlease enter valid input.",
                                "Invalid Input",
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            else if (randomNumber > guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You guessed too low.\nGuess again!", "Your guess",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else if (randomNumber < guess1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You guessed too high.\nGuess again!",
                        "Your guess", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            else {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null,
                                "You guessed the number right!\nIt took you "
                                        + attempts + " attempt(s) to guess it.",
                                "Congratulations!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Want to play again?", "Play again?",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("Play again soon!");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
                    System.out.println(randomNumber);
                    attempts = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That actually helped me quite a bit, especially with understanding the while loop. Thanks again! Oh and thank you for pointing out that I didn't need the UIManager. I had that in another program an forgot to take that part out. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need an instance of that class. But note I changed this: `m1.put("OptionPane.background", lg);` for this: `UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", lg);`

Answer (score 0):

**Use a while loop.**

Here's an example of how to keep looping until some condition is met (in this case, if a number is between 1 and 100 inclusive):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    boolean good = false;
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
      number = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(number > 0 && number <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Good choice: \"" + number + "\"!");
        good = true;
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Invalid number: \"" + number + "\"! Please enter a number between 1 and 100!\n");
    }
    while (!good);
 }
```

Sample input:

```
-1 -2 0 1
```

Output:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 100: 
Invalid number: "-1"! Please enter a number between 1 and 100!

Enter a number between 1 and 100: 
Invalid number: "-2"! Please enter a number between 1 and 100!

Enter a number between 1 and 100: 
Invalid number: "0"! Please enter a number between 1 and 100!

Enter a number between 1 and 100: 
Good choice: "1"!
```

Answer (score 0):

It went in an infinite loop when the correct number is not guessed.  I have made some alterations to your code, see if this helps.

```
    package com.ananth.stackoverflow.help;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class RandomNumberGuesser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager m1 = new UIManager();
        Color g = Color.gray;
        Color lg = g.brighter();
        m1.put("OptionPane.background", lg);
        m1.put("Panel.background", lg);

        int x;
        for (x = 1; true; x++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(randomNumber);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "This program will generate a random number from 0 to 100 which you have to guess.", "Number Guesser",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            String guess = getInputFromUser();
            int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);

            int y;
            for (y = 1; true; y++) {
                if (guess1 > 100 || guess1 < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guess is out of range!\nPlease enter valid input.",
                            "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else if (randomNumber == guess1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed the number right!\nIt took you " + y
                            + " attempt(s) to guess it.", "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                        System.out.println("Play again soon!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        y = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (randomNumber > guess1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed too low.\nGuess again!", "Your guess",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    guess = getInputFromUser();
                    guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);
                } else if (randomNumber < guess1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed too high.\nGuess again!", "Your guess",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    guess = getInputFromUser();
                    guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getInputFromUser() {
        String guess = "";
        guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Guess a number.", "Guess", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (guess == null) {
            System.out.println("The user has terminated the program");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return guess;
    }
}
```